how to get a new zsavepos for each invocation of a command
In order to check when a margin overfills, I need to calculate the distance to the bottom. I hope I can do this with the \zsavepos command, but cannot see how I can have a new position determined for each invocation of the command. - Is there another approach?
The MWE takes just the position of the first invocation and then repeats the same value each time, not giving the actual position. In another related question for each invocation a different position id is given each time; I need an automatic approach.
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\maintext}{\lipsum[75]}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{zref-savepos} 

\newcommand{\getpos}%
    {%
        \zsavepos{begin}
        \par CURRPOS \the\dimexpr \zposy{begin}sp
        % 
    }

\begin{document} 
    \getpos
    \maintext
    \getpos
    \maintext 
    \getpos
 
\end{document}


you need some counter mypos. Then you can do \zsavebox{begin\themypos}.

Thank you for the recommendation. Is \zsavepos expensive in terms of runtime? I wonder if I follow a good path to avoid overfilling the margin.

well the main problem with the approach is, that if you do something based on the position, you normally change the position and on the next compilation then you perhaps undo your change again.

The typical way of doing this entails the creation of a counter that is stepped with each invocation and used as part of the position label.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{zref-savepos} 

\newcounter{zposysave}
\newcommand{\getpos}{%
  \stepcounter{zposysave}% Step counter
  \zsaveposy{posy-\thezposysave}% Save y position
  \par CURRPOS \the\dimexpr \zposy{posy-\thezposysave}sp~% Recall/print y position
}

\begin{document} 

\getpos
\lipsum[75]
\getpos
\lipsum[75]
\getpos
 
\end{document}


Thank you for the coded solution. I will build it in and hope it achieves what I hope for.
